# How to sort so that caml is after c in an xml?

Tags: sorting

Sorting a file with lines

```
<LexerType name="caml" desc="Caml" ext="">
<LexerType name="c" desc="C" ext="">
```

causes caml to be before c, how do I put c first in general, without relying on the character positions of this file?

Comment: What program are you using to sort the lines, and how are you invoking it?  Just doing a bytewise comparison should get you the results you want.

Comment: I'm using sort (GNU coreutils) 8.5.

Comment: For me, just running `sort` on those two lines causes the "c" line to be printed before the "caml" line, so something else must be going on.  Does the "caml" line contain extra leading whitespace in your file?

Comment: Yes, both lines contain the same amount of leading spaces.

Comment: Odd, because even if you're usingg some brain-dead search that isn't aware of xml, c" (c double-quote) should sort before ca.

Comment: Try adding LC_ALL=C before sort invocation, e.g. "LC_ALL=C sort ...", maybe it's a locale issue, thus you're getting weird sort order.

Comment: I tried that, no change. I also tried using perl, and it sorts properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### using `sort`

```
$ sort -t\" -k2,2 file.xml
<LexerType name="c" desc="C" ext=""/>
<LexerType name="caml" desc="Caml" ext=""/>
```

---

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
   -t, --field-separator=SEP
          use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
```

### using `vim`

```
:%sort /name=/
```

or

```
:%sort r /name="\w*"/
```

---

```
:[range]sor[t][!] [i][u][r][n][x][o] [/{pattern}/]

                    When /{pattern}/ is specified and there is no [r] flag
                    the text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so that
                    you sort on what comes after the match.
                    Instead of the slash any non-letter can be used.
                    For example, to sort on the second comma-separated
                    field: >
                            :sort /[^,]*,/
                    To sort on the text at virtual column 10 (thus
                    ignoring the difference between tabs and spaces): >
                            :sort /.*\%10v/
                    To sort on the first number in the line, no matter
                    what is in front of it: >
                            :sort /.*\ze\d/

                    With [r] sorting is done on the matching {pattern}
                    instead of skipping past it as described above.
                    For example, to sort on only the first three letters
                    of each line: >
                            :sort /\a\a\a/ r
```